# Why can't I break out of a loop when catching StopIteration?

Tags: python, exception, for-loop

I need to catch exceptions thrown by `next(it)` so I can't use a regular `for` loop in this case. So I wrote this code:

```
it = iter(xrange(5))
while True:
    try:
        num = it.next()
        print(num)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) # log and ignore
    except StopIteration:
        break
print('finished')
```

This doesn't work, after the numbers are exhausted I get an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out `StopIteration` is actually a subclass of `Exception`, not just another throwable class. So the `StopIteration` handler was never called since `StopIteration` is alrady handled by the one for `Exception`. I just had to put the `StopIteration` handler on top:

```
it = iter(xrange(5))
while True:
    try:
        num = it.next()
        print(num)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e) # log and ignore
print('finished')
```

Comment: Of course, the best answer is not to catch `Exception`, instead only catching specific ones.

Comment: In general I agree of course, but in this case catching `Exception` was the right thing to do. (I have to do a large number of independent calculations which takes a couple of days. So I just log which ones fail; later I can fix the bug that caused this and recalculate only what's needed.)

Comment: Fair enough - there are always specific cases where it is the right call.